# My $watch isn't firing

Tags: angularjs

I have what I think is a garden-variety `$watch` set up, but it sure isn't working.

**[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyennis/h714huat/1/)**  When you click the buttons, the `fac.backingFabric` attribute will be updated - you can see it happening due to the two-way binding.  But the `$watch` isn't happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You watch has no issues it is firing properly. But you have issues inside the watcher. You are looking for undefined variable `fac` where you should be looking for `$scope.fac`.

```
$scope.$watch("fac.backingFabric", function () {
    alert($scope.fac.backingFabric);
    $scope.out = "out" + $scope.fac.backingFabric;
});
```

Infact you can look for the first argument of the watch function.

```
$scope.$watch("fac.backingFabric", function (value) {
     $scope.out = "out" + value;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. So simple but I don't know how long it would have taken me to find it.

Comment: You are welcome. WHen in doubt first check the console for any errors, it will give you lots of clues... :)